# IdentityServer4 API Key Support

Tags: asp.net-core, api-key, identityserver4

I have 3 projects in Visual Studio.

1. Identity Server
2. API Site
3. Angular 2 front end

I'm using IdentityServer4 with ASP.NET Core Identity and Entity Framework. Everything is working great so far.

Now, I want to add the ability for users to generate an API key so the user can make calls to our API server via their server and simply pass in the API Key. That will then (somehow) authenticate the user and generate an Access Token used by my API for authorization. Does IdentityServer4 support generating API keys for each user? I know there are client secrets, which I have implemented but that only identifies the client. I need to know the user too so I know what the user is authorized to do (using roles right now for that).

Comment: What's the difference between an API key per user and a user password?

Comment: Good question. The API Key can be used without having the users username/password in the API call. I'm looking into this only to provide external developers with an experience similar to using Google APIs, Swipe, StormPath, and many other API providers.

Comment: Any updates on this? Does IdentityServer4 support Api Keys?

Comment: Any update on this? The accepted answer does not answer the question as mentioned by @206mph.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> IdentityServer is a framework and a hostable component that allows
>   implementing single sign-on and access control for modern web
>   applications and APIs using protocols like OpenID Connect and OAuth2.
>   It supports a wide range of clients like mobile, web, SPAs and desktop
>   applications and is extensible to allow integration in new and
>   existing architectures.
>       
>   in your startup class:

```cs
     public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
                {
                    var source = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("MyCertificate.b64cert");
                    var certBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(source);
                    var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certBytes, "password");

                    var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
                    {
                        options.SigningCertificate = certificate;
                        options.RequireSsl = false; // should be true
                    });
             JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
        app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
            options.ScopeName = "openid";
            options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
            options.AutomaticChallenge = true;
        });
                    builder.AddInMemoryClients(Clients.Get());
                    builder.AddInMemoryScopes(Scopes.Get());
                    builder.AddInMemoryUsers(Users.Get());
                }

            public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
                    {
                        loggerFactory.AddConsole(LogLevel.Verbose);
                        loggerFactory.AddDebug(LogLevel.Verbose);
                        app.UseIdentityServer();
                    }
```

create a Clients class

```cs
public class Clients
{
    public static IEnumerable<Client> Get()
    {
        return new[]
        {
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "myapi",
                ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                },
                ClientName = "your api",
                Flow = Flows.ResourceOwner,
                AllowedScopes =
                {
                    Constants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    "read"
                },
                Enabled = true
            }
        };
    }
}
```

scopes

```cs
public class Scopes
{
    public static IEnumerable<Scope> Get()
    {
        return new[]
        {
            StandardScopes.OpenId,
            StandardScopes.Profile,
            StandardScopes.OfflineAccess,
            new Scope {Name = "advanced", DisplayName = "Advanced Options"}
        };
    }
}
```

controller

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    [Authorize]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }
}
```

once this is setup, you can issue the JWT authentication token that the user can then use in their Authorization header

create a generating class

```cs
private async Task GenerateToken(HttpContext context)
{
    var username = context.Request.Form["username"];
    var password = context.Request.Form["password"];

    var identity = await GetIdentity(username, password);
    if (identity == null)
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 400;
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Invalid username or password.");
        return;
    }

    var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

    // Specifically add the jti (random nonce), iat (issued timestamp), and sub (subject/user) claims.
    // You can add other claims here, if you want:
    var claims = new Claim[]
    {
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, username),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, now.ToUnixTimeSeconds().ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.Integer64)
    };

    // Create the JWT and write it to a string
    var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(
        issuer: _options.Issuer,
        audience: _options.Audience,
        claims: claims,
        notBefore: now,
        expires: now.Add(_options.Expiration),
        signingCredentials: _options.SigningCredentials);
    var encodedJwt = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwt);

    var response = new
    {
        access_token = encodedJwt,
        expires_in = (int)_options.Expiration.TotalSeconds
    };

    // Serialize and return the response
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    await context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response, new JsonSerializerSettings { Formatting = Formatting.Indented }));
}
```

create your middleware:

```cs
using System;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace SimpleTokenProvider
{
    public class TokenProviderMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly TokenProviderOptions _options;

        public TokenProviderMiddleware(
            RequestDelegate next,
            IOptions<TokenProviderOptions> options)
        {
            _next = next;
            _options = options.Value;
        }

        public Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            // If the request path doesn't match, skip
            if (!context.Request.Path.Equals(_options.Path, StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
                return _next(context);
            }

            // Request must be POST with Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
            if (!context.Request.Method.Equals("POST")
               || !context.Request.HasFormContentType)
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 400;
                return context.Response.WriteAsync("Bad request.");
            }

            return GenerateToken(context);
        }
    }
}
```

and lastly wireup your middleware for generating the tokens in your startup.cs

```cs
app.UseMiddleware<TokenProviderMiddleware>(Options.Create(options));
```

Comment: Thanks for all the code! However, this generates an access token from what I can tell from the code. I'm new to this type of security so please bare with me. My current solution already creates and passes access tokens, which is great. However, if you go to Google's Developer Console, you can create API keys that allow you to access their APIs using the key(not access token). Sample key: 'AIzaSyBeOqHuSDFjHrpZWCyRWgT3nzIZHkWCjrRg'. This is much shorter than an access token. Each user can have several API keys issues for each of their apps that may use it. I don't know how to create these.

Comment: Ah sorry about that. I'd suggest then creating your own provider for that. Create and store the base.64 codes in a table that maps to a users identity. Then when ur API is accessed it will check if the code is active and exists and has the appropriate permissions.

Comment: If ur looking to just create the keys use sha256()

Comment: @206mph are you just looking to generate the keys?

Comment: @Marcus, Could you elaborate and provide some code sample? How the API will check if the code is active ?

Comment: @Yanal-YvesFargialla ASP Net Core Identity middleware looks after that verification for you using the claims that you assign. A great tutorial for this stuff is https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLOeFnOV9YBa7dnrjpOG6lMpcyd7Wn7E8V it walks you through the how and why. It is quite basic, but it will get you up to speed. I recommend not checking the token yourself- use ASP net core Identity to manage everything. Decorate your controllers and methods for policies you create and assign users, APIs etc. It does all the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: @Yanal-YvesFargialla Following up, I think creating a new question for this topic is the next step here. How an API checks if the code is active, is what the middleware is handling. with decoration of the exposed endpoints within your application. Identity Server needs to be aware of what APIs and their respective endpoints are authorized by IdentityServer. You need to set the scope of the authorization.